# Change insets for each section in a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, collectionview, sections

I have a simple `UICollectionView` written in Swift. My sectionInsets used to be 0, 35, 0, 35 which gave the entire collectionView margins left end right. My minimumLineSpacing is set to default 10, which means all of my cells have a margin of 10 between each other. All good.

Then I divided the `UICollectionView` into two sections. The first section serves to hold a cell that acts as a prompt to create a new cell (which will end up in section 2). The second section holds all other cells (the actual content).

My problem is that ever since I added the second section, the spacing between the one static cell in section 1 and the first cell in section 2 isn't 10 anymore but 35+10. I'm now trying to get this particular spacing back to 10.

My thought was to add an if condition to identify whether it's section 1 or 2 and set the sectionInsets accordingly. I'm stuck however as to where and how exactly I should do this. I don't seem to be able to call sectionInsets or FlowLayout from my View Controller at e.g. cellForItemAtIndexPath. Should I do it in my CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout subclass? Here is the code that I have in there.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(305.0, 407.0);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20.0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0;
    self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 35, 0, 35);
}
```

And this is the code for my sections in my view controller:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let firstCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("createCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CreateCollectionViewCell
        firstCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "puppy3")
        return firstCell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
I figured it out. It works for me by adding two variables for sectionInsets of type UIEdgeInsets in my view controller and then adding this function:

```
//Set custom insets per section
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if section == 0 {
        return sectionInsets1
    } else {
        return sectionInsets2
    }
}
```